# Нужна помощь с гуглом

Tags: html

пару часов назад я изменил тег `<title>` на своем сайте, вписал свою ссылку в браузере и вроде все изменилось, но когда я написал в поисковой строке гугла site:(тут ссылка на сайт) то я увидел что там тайтл не изменился. Что делать? В чем может быть проблема? (Если что я зарегистрирован в Google Search Console)

Comment: кэш браузера почистили?

Comment: Подождать несколько дней, пока гугл переиндексирует сайт?

Comment: В гугле тайтл меняется не сразу?

Comment: @jediAllen не только в гугле, но и в любых поисковых системах меняется не сразу

Comment: А почему должно меняться сразу? Думаете, робот гугла ежесекундно проверяет вашу страницу не изменилось ли там чего?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не о программировании совсем. И "с гуглом" тут помочь никто не сможет, вряд ли Брин и Пейдж сюда заходят.

Comment: вот такие вот ребята берут в работу сайты на сео-продвижение за 500р, обваливая рынок.

Answer (score 1):

Запросить переиндексирование отдельной страницы через Yandex Веб-мастер и в Google Search Console (копируете URL-адрес, нажимаете проверка URL, а там в результатах находите "Запросить индексирование"). Титл изменится сразу после того, как поисковый робот снова посетит вашу страницу и переиндексирует её (от 5 до 30 дней в среднем).